# My code isn't overwriting the text file, even though it should be?

Tags: c++, text-files, overwrite

We did a very similar type of code in C++ class but my version isn't working right, even though it is line-by-line (almost) the same.

My code is meant to save a user's Pokemon and they can add and delete as they please. My display function is working but my add and delete function are not. All the files are opening, but it's not overwriting the file like it's supposed to. Really unsure of what to do, I'm very much a beginner and I don't know much.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
string name[100];
string type[100];
int level[100];
string newPokemon;
string newType;
int newLevel;
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
int numberOfPokemon = 0;
//Input Pokemon Info
cout << "Name of Pokemon: ";
getline(cin, newPokemon);
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << "Pokemon type: ";
getline(cin, newType);
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << "Pokemon level: "; //weird gap between "Pokemon type" and "pokemon level". I have to press enter twice from "pokemon type" to get to "pokemon level"
cin >> newLevel;
cin.ignore(5, '\n');
fin.open("pokemon.txt");
//Put file in array
if (fin.is_open())
{
    while (isalnum(fin.peek()) && numberOfPokemon < 100)
    {
        getline(fin, name[numberOfPokemon]);
        getline(fin, type[numberOfPokemon]);
        fin >> level[numberOfPokemon];
        fin.ignore(100, '\n');
        if (name[numberOfPokemon] != newPokemon)
            numberOfPokemon++;
    }
    fin.close();
}
//Output file
fout.open("pokemon.txt");
if (fout.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPokemon; i++)
    {
        fout << name[i] << "\n";
        fout << type[i] << "\n";
        fout << level[i] << "\n";

    }
    //Tack on new piece
    fout << newPokemon << "\n";
    fout << newType << "\n";
    fout << newLevel << "\n";
    fout.close();
    cout << "Add Successful\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Add Failure\n";
}
```

and now my delete function:

```
string name[100];
string type[100];
int level[100];
int pokemonCount = 0;
string deletedPokemon = "";
bool found = false;

ifstream fin;

cout << "Which Pokemon would you like to delete?" << endl;
getline(cin, deletedPokemon);
cin.ignore(5, '\n');

fin.open("pokemon.txt");
if (fin.is_open())
{
    while (isalnum(fin.peek()))
    {
        getline(fin, name[pokemonCount]);
        getline(fin, type[pokemonCount]);
        fin >> level[pokemonCount];
        fin.clear();
        fin.ignore(100, '\n');
        if (deletedPokemon == name[pokemonCount])
        {
            pokemonCount--;
            found = true;
        }
        pokemonCount++;
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << "ya the file opened" << endl; //always appears
}

ofstream fout;
fout.open("pokemon.txt");
if (fout.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pokemonCount; i++)
    {
        fout << name[i] << "\n";
        fout << type[i] << "\n";
        fout << level[i] << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
    cout << "pokemon removed\n";
    cout << "the file opened."; //it is returning that the file opened in both occasions in this function but nothing is happening!
}
else
{
   cout << "removal failure";
   cout << "The file didn't open";
}
return found;
```

at the end of this function (if I chose to delete one), it will offer the "Would you like to add a Pokemon?" but it wont let me input an answer and it will just end the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour of [`ofstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) is to simply open the file for reading and writing. If you want to overwrite the file, you need to specify it in your call to `open`.

```
fout.open("pokemon.txt", ios_base::in|ios_base::out|ios_base::trunc);
```

Comment: Ah of course. I forgot about that. Well I replaced both of my fout.open in both of the functions with that line but it still returns the one I tried to delete. Thank you though!

Comment: @Hannah What do you mean delete? I assumed you want to erase the existing contents of "pokemon.txt" and replace it with whatever you are doing in the loop after the `open`. This code should do that.

Comment: Well I am trying to eliminate a specific record in the text file. For instance, in this file it displays the name, type, and level. When it prompts me to remove a record, I enter the name. The program should be removing the name, type, and level of that particular entry. Even after changing the fout.open (in both the add & delete functions - both supposed to be overwriting) it still doesn't change the text file. You are right, it is supposed to be overwriting but for some reason, this isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is not marked as read-only under properties.

Also, there is a bug in your delete function:

The bfound should be replace with nDelete pokemon and when you write out the file:

```
    if (deletedPokemon == name[pokemonCount])
    {
        pokemonCount--;
        found = true;
        nDeleteIndex = i;
    }
....
    for (int i = 0; i < pokemonCount; i++)
    {

    if(i == nDeleteIndex)
        continue;
    fout << name[i] << "\n";
    fout << type[i] << "\n";
    fout << level[i] << endl;
    }
```

Right now it will re-write all your pokemons without skipping the one you want to delete!

Also, what happens if the user has 155 pokemons for a full index. You want to use:

```
 std::vector<string> names;
 ....
 string szPokemon;
 getline(fin, name[numberOfPokemon]);
 names.push_back(szPokemon);
```

Thus you no longer have a limit !

Comment: That's a good idea but I checked it and it's available for read and write. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where to put the i == nDeletePokemon? And good catch on the 155 pokemon index! How would I use the std::vector<string> names; ? Thank you for the help!

Comment: int nDeleteIndex = -1; keeps track of which pokemon to delete. If its still -1 after the find pokemon then we failed to find the pokemon and return. Otherwise when we write out the file just skip the pokemon when you hit nDeleteIndex.

Comment: okay so I've declared int nDeleteIndex = -1 at the top, and included the rest of the portion. It is telling me that i isn't declared above the for statement. Where should I declare it? @Gary Kaizer

Comment: Declare it with the names so its in the full function scope. Also remove the pokemonCount--; statement. If all fails make it write "test" for the name thus letting you know that its a write error or a logic error.

Comment: I declared it up at the top and it doesn't change anything when I run it. Rats!!

Comment: Change nDeleteIndex=pokemonCount; and remove the pokemonCount--

Comment: okay I changed the nDeleteIndex = 1; to nDeleteIndex = pokmeonCount; and removed the pokemonCount--; and it still doesn't work. I hope it's not just my computer. Now something weird happened. It cycled the for statement three times (it showed the "pokemon removed" three times) and now the only Pokemon is the one I was trying to delete.

Comment: Have you tried writing.the name as Test just to make sure ?

Comment: You're right, I just tried test and it returned with the first Pokemon by itself again.

Comment: Delete the file and see if you are looking at the correct file

Comment: I deleted it and it created a new one when I ran it. I put it back again and the list appeared again.

Comment: I put in that line and it made my remaining pokemon double, now there's two entries of the same thing. It's okay because I rewrote my code with some functions that my other classmates had and now it works. No clue why because it's line for line the same thing, but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is much cleaner code, its much more maintainable and whenever you add/remove a field from the pokemon (Shiny? Male/Female ? Unique ?) you will be able to easily do it inside the CPokemonObject instead of having to copy paste the code 100 times.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
#define POKEMON_FILE "Pokemon.txt"

class CPokemon
{
public:
    string szName;
    string szType;
    int nLevel;
    CPokemon() : szName("Pika"), nLevel(10), szType("Lightning")
    {};

    void Read(ifstream &file)
    {
        file >> szName;
        file >> szType;
        file >> nLevel;
    };

    void Write(ofstream &file)
    {
        file << szName << endl;
        file << szType << endl;
        file << nLevel << endl;
    };

    void CreatePokemon()
    {
        //Input Pokemon Info
        cout << "Name of Pokemon: ";
        getline(cin, szName);
        cout << "Pokemon type: ";
        getline(cin, szType);
        cout << "Pokemon level: "; //weird gap between "Pokemon type" and "pokemon level". I have to press enter twice from "pokemon type" to get to "pokemon level"
        cin >> nLevel;
    }
};

void WritePokemons(vector<CPokemon>& Pokemons)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(POKEMON_FILE);

    //check the file open
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << "removal failure";
        cout << "The file didn't open";
        return;
    }

    //Write out all the pokemons
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Pokemons.size(); i++)  
        Pokemons[i].Write(fout);

    fout.close();
}

void ReadPokemons(vector<CPokemon>& Pokemons)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(POKEMON_FILE);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        while (isalnum(fin.peek()))
        {
            CPokemon Pokemon;
            Pokemon.Read(fin);
            Pokemons.push_back(Pokemon);
        }
        fin.close();
        cout << "ya the file opened" << endl; //always appears
    }
}

bool DeletePokemon()
{
    vector<CPokemon> Pokemons;

    string szPokemonToDelete = "";
    cout << "Which Pokemon would you like to delete?" << endl;
    cin >> szPokemonToDelete;

    //Read all pokemons
    ReadPokemons(Pokemons);

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("pokemon.txt");

    //check the file open
    if (!fout.is_open())
    {
        cout << "removal failure";
        cout << "The file didn't open";
        return false;
    }

    bool bFound = false;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Pokemons.size(); i++)      
    {
        //Skip the pokemon to delete
        if(Pokemons[i].szName == szPokemonToDelete)
        {
            bFound = true; //we found the pokemon to delete
            continue;
        }

        Pokemons[i].Write(fout);
    }

    fout.close();

    return bFound;
}

void AddPokemon()
{
    vector<CPokemon> Pokemons;

    //Read all pokemons from the file
    ReadPokemons(Pokemons);

    //Create the new porkemon
    CPokemon Pokemon;
    Pokemon.CreatePokemon();

    //Add the pokemon to the list
    Pokemons.push_back(Pokemon);

    //Output file
    WritePokemons(Pokemons);
}
```

Comment: Holy crud this is awesome! Although I fixed the code for my class, I will definitely be using this when I play through Pokemon X! Thank you so much! This is much more advanced that what I currently know but it will be so useful! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, the reason I made this little program is that as you can see the read/write alone became unmanagable pretty quickly every time you added a field to the pokemon and if you had to pass the pokemon to any object you would have to pass all the variables. Thus instead of doing **DrawPokemon(string name,string type, string shiny, string age....)** you can easily instead do **DrawPokemon(CPokemon &Pokemon)**, also not the '&'  in front of pokemon, which is used to let the compiler know to use the pointer instead of copying the whole object every time.